# Classification of objects from a video ( human, animals, others(cars etc.,) )

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, computer-vision, object-detection

Hi I am new to image processing field. My project is to classify the objects in an image/Video.
The input is an image/video from surveillance camera. I should classify the objects into three classes. 1) Humans 2) Animals 3) Others (cars). We can consider a fixed background.

Can any one suggest any proven algorithms or papers or opensource code for this purpose? offcourse googling is obvious solution but always an experienced eye is always helpful!

Comment: The question you are asking could serve as a PhD thesis topic. It's *way* too broad for StackOverflow. Maybe the digital signal processing stack exchange is better suited for it.

Comment: @EMS I have posted the same in Digital signal processing and here is the link http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/classification-of-objects-from-a-video-image-human-animals-otherscars-etc#comment8755_4750

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your purposes, I think the best option is [*LatSVM*](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~rbg/latent/) because the authors disponibilizes the implementation in MATLAB and the detector models already trained. The already trained models includes:

- Aeroplane, Boat, Bus, Car, Bicycle
- Bottle, TV, Sofa
- Bird, Cat, Horse, Sheep, Dog
- *etc.*

There is also an implementation in OpenCV if you need (found out in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11832447/957997)).

**Other Detector Implementations**

- [VeryFast Detector](http://rodrigob.github.com/)
- [Partial Least Squares](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~william/softwares.html)
- [FPDW](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/research.html)

---

Give a look at the following surveys in Pedestrian Detection:

1. Pedestrian Detection: An Evaluation of the State of the Art (2012).
2. Survey of Pedestrian Detection for Advanced Driver Assistance Systems (2010).

**State of Art**

- *Pedestrian detection at 100 frames per second*. This work proposed by [Benenson *et al.*, 2012] achieves a high detection speed with state-of-art precision [[webpage](http://rodrigob.github.com/)].
- *Object Detection with Discriminatively Trained Part Based Models* aka *LatSVM* Achieved good results on PASCAL 2006, 2007 and 2008. This work doesn't show only for pedestrian detection, but also for cars, cats, horse, sofa *etc*. You really should give a look at this one [[webpage](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~rbg/latent/)]
- *Human Detection using Partial Least Squares Analysis*. [Schwartz *et al., 2009]* proposed the use of Partial Least Squares analysis which allows to handle high-dimensional space features.

**Classical Works**

The following works has important contributions and are references in every work of pedestrian detection. HOG feature, Integral Image, and Cascade of Rejection are used by several works, including the one by [Benenson *et al.*, 2012].

- *Histograms of Oriented Gradients for Human Detection*
- *Fast Human Detection Using a Cascade of Histograms of Oriented Gradients*

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. I have edited my question please have a look. The input may be image or video.

Comment: give a look at the links I've put in my answer. They also disponibilize their source code. The *Object Detection (...)* already has trained models for what you want. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!Am waiting for your update.

Comment: I posted the same in Digital Signal processing in Stack exchange and here is the link.  http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/classification-of-objects-from-a-video-image-human-animals-otherscars-etc#comment8755_4750  I got a response suggesting http://www.vlfeat.org/. Please have a look and your views and suggestions will be greatfull.

Comment: Please have a look at my another post also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024141/face-authentication

Comment: Hi, @user1317084 -- I'll take a look at these questions, maybe I can contribute with something. I could not check them yet because I'm in a rush this week. Thanks for inviting me :)